# Does the code of a Node.js child process get parsed every time it gets spawned?

Tags: node.js

It is common practice to outsource a long running task to a child process. Now, I have a long running function (which would block the event loop for several seconds) which I would like to outsource to a child process. Everytime this function gets called, a child process gets spawned and it gets closed after the function returns. Does Node.js somehow cache the intermedidiate representation of that code or does it get parsed every time the child process spawns? And does the code ever get optimized under those conditions?

Fortunately, from what I measured, spawning a child process doesn't add as much of an overhead as I feared it would. But nonetheless, if the code gets parsed every time and never gets optimized it would be a loss of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Node.js somehow cache the intermediate representation of that code or does it get parsed every time the child process spawns?

Assuming you're talking about `child_process.spawn()`, that starts an entirely new process and if you're running a node.js program, it will be an entirely new node.js process that will read the code from disk from scratch and parse it again.

> And does the code ever get optimized under those conditions?

It's unclear what you mean by "does the code ever get optimized".  Node.js will do the same optimizations it always does when running in your main process or in a process started with `spawn()`.

A more efficient way to do this rather than starting a new process each time might be to create a lasting worker process that you start a few of and then a work queue and you pass work items to each worker process.  They do the work and return the result and keep running waiting for the next work work item.  You can use any number of interprocess communication methods to communicate with the worker processes from the built-in stdio and stdout communication all the way to making each one an http server on it's own local port that you can send requests to.

This is worker process and work queue is how you would avoid the overhead of starting and shutting down new processes all the time.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about `child_process.spawn()`.

Comment: What I meant with optimization is that V8 needs a warmup to produce optimized code. And because the spawned process doesn't live long in my scenario, this would never happen. Or at least that was my understanding which you confirmed. 
Thank you for that and your advice how to deal with such a problem more efficiently.

Comment: @MarvinH. - Not sure what a warmup is?  Child process will have same optimizations as parent, but redone from scratch each time which is slightly inefficient. Persistent worker processes may be more efficient.